# Parsing XML with jQuery for mobile devices such as iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

I have built a web application using jQuery and it is working perfectly in a browser on a computer but I can not for the life of me get it to work on my mobile iPad. It is a critical part of the website and expect a lot of traffic coming from mobile devices so I really need this to work. I am very very new to programming so any help is appreciated getting this to work :). Thanks!

I am working in Drupal to lay out my website so jQuery is written out instead of the $ sign. The javascript wont work if i do not write it out.

Here is the web application working on the computer :

http://www.famousartistprints.com/content/select-house-design

Here is the code:

```
    <div id="settingHeight"><ul data-role="listview" id="list" class="tilelist" > </ul><div>
```

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery.get('http://www.famousartistprints.com/xml/designs.xml',function(data){

         jQuery(data).find('slide').each(function(){
                var slide = jQuery(this);
                var caption = slide.find('caption').text();
                var source = slide.find('source').text()
                var html = '<li class="mySlides"><a href="' + caption + '_Letterpress_Wedding_Invitation"><img src="/sites/aerialist.localhost/files/images/selectThumbs/' + source + '"/><p>' + caption + '</p><a>';      
                 jQuery('#list').append(html);
                   jQuery('#list').hide();
                jQuery('#list').fadeIn(800);
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: when you say it's not working on the ipad, what do you mean?

Comment: Hi Andy, Nothing appears where the images are supposed to pop up; I'm guessing that the iPad is not grabbing the XML data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because of the way different browsers handle syntax errors, which your code has.

Even if you run this on the desktop, notice that the browser console tells you about a syntax error on line 584. Fix this and you should be ok.

[image: screenshot of console]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I fixed the syntax errors and that did not fix the issue :(. I wish it was that easy. Any other thoughts?

Comment: hey graig, I added a comment to your main question